# WPF Parent with WinForm Child - BringToFront() not working

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a WPF application with a menuItem that will call a WinForm Form. I am able to open the WinForm from the WPF window, but it opens behind the WPF window. It will not move to the front of the WPF window. I can interact with the WinForm window just fine.

Here is the code I use to launch the WinForm

```
void ManualControlInit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    // Set visual styles
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    DynamixelCsDemo form = new DynamixelCsDemo();
    WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    wih.Owner = form.Handle;
    form.Show();
    form.BringToFront();
}
```

How can I open the WinForm and have it show on top of the WPF window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that implements `IWin32Window`, return the WPF window's handle from its `Handle`, and pass that class to `form.Show()`.

This will set the form as owned by the window.

Comment: I am getting the error "The best overloaded match has some invalid arguments" when passing the IWin32Window object via `form.Show(window);` Do I need to create an override method for `Show()` in the WinForm class definition?

Comment: Then you passed the wrong object.  WPF does not implement `IWin32Window`; you need to make a wrapper yourself.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was not paying attention to my implementation of the helper. Visual Studio was referencing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.iwin32window%28v=vs.110%29.aspx from System.Windows.Interop. Everything is working great. Thanks for your help.